# Why when using RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} always I get null?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I would like to ask why when using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` always I get null.

```
<TextBlock Tag="{Binding SomeValue}" Text="{Binding SomeValue, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type EnumModel:SomeEnum},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TargetUpdated">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type v:MyView}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

I have solved it by using `ElementName` instead like the following:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtSortDirection" Tag="{Binding SomeValue}" Text="{Binding SomeValue, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type EnumModel:SomeEnum},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TargetUpdated">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type v:MyView}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, ElementName=txtSortDirection}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

but I still wonder why I get null when I use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` used to get this **binding property belongs element** as the binding source.

**And only works on the `UIElement`**.

You're try to use it on `i:InvokeCommandAction` in `Trigger`, but ***It's not an `UIElement`***.

Btw: But it works on the `DataTrigger`.